# Question About The Intersection Of 3 Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a question about the following simultaneous equation problem:
[image]

I was able to reduce this system to: $y + 2z = 1$ and $(k^2 - 4)z = k - 2$. However, the case that is confusing me is when $k = 2$. If $k = 2$, there will be an infinte amount of solutions, as an infinte amount of pairs satisfy $y + 2z = 1$ and $0 = 0$.

So this means that for every x-value, there is an infinite amount of pairs that satisfy all 3 equations (the pairs being all that satisfy: $y + 2z = 1$).

My question is, would this mean that the intersection between these 3 equations would be a plane, because for each x-value, the equations are satisfied by $y + 2z = 1$? And if so, how is that possible? I can't visualize how the intersection between 3 non-identical planes can be a plane?

And if not, why wouldn't the above mean that the intersection between these 3 equations would be a plane? Because for every x-value, we have an infinite amount of x and y values that satisfy the syste.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $k = 2$, first and third equations are same. So it is intersection of $2$ planes for $k = 2$.

Comment: Also first two planes intersect in a line as they are not parallel. Now based on values of $k$ in the third, it is possible that there is a point where all $3$ of them intersect (common point on all three planes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens to the third equation when you put $k=2$? It basically becomes the first equation, hence you only have two unique equations on three variables $(x,y,z)$

The intersection of these two planes is the line $2y+z = 1$, think of it like the hinge between the two planes which are described by the plane equations

If you had a third equation which was not linearly dependent, the intersection of the plane and the above line could either be a single point or no solutions(if parallel).